# How to read the entire resultSet data obtained from the query without using while loop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, ucanaccess

I am having a resultSet which contains data fetched from the query after which i want to print all the data captured without using while loop, below is my sample code

```java
@Autowired
private OrderRepository orderRepository;

String msAccDB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + datafile.mdb;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(msAccDB);

Statement orders = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result = orders
                        .executeQuery("SELECT [ORDERID], [ORDERDATE], [QUANTIRY], [PAYMENT] FROM [ORDERS]");
                
            while (result.next()) {
                Order order = new Order();
                order.setOrderId(result.getString("ORDERID"));
                order.setOrderDate(result.getString("ORDERDATE"));
                order.setQuantity(result.getString("QUANTIRY"));
                order.setPayment(result.getString("PAYMENT"));
                orderRepository.save(order);
            }                

result.close();
orders.close();
```

Using while loop takes much time to complete since the mdb file that is being read is large in size of about 1GB, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot, as this is the way JDBC works.

Comment: Also in spring you have better options than raw jdbc. But whatever you do will have a while loop involved. The problem isn't the while loop.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum and Nathan Hughes for your quick response so what do you suggest I should do in order to read that file in fraction of a second if am to use the while without taking much time?

Comment: Without seeing your actual code (there is no while loop here) there is not much we can tell about increasing performance for your code. Forget about reading it in a fraction of a second that will never happen with such a large dataset.

Comment: ok I m editing my post to add while loop

Comment: There is still not enough information. You are reading from something, then writing to something. What is this `OrderRepository`? Where is the transaction defined? Is it JPA, is it JDBC is it???? So many questions...

Comment: yes sure @M.Deinum can you please check your email for me

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JPA for this kind of processing. It just adds overhead that you don't seem to need.

Instead use a `JdbcTemplate` to execute an insert.
Use the batch features to reduce the overhead of database round trips.

Access `ResultSet` values by index, instead of by name. Some drivers seem to be rather inefficient with names.

While you're at it you might want to use `JdbcTemplate` also for the original query. Makes for simpler code and fixes your exception handling.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jens Schauder can you plase add some simple code block on how to use JdbcTemplate to execute an insert and how to use the batch features to reduce the overhead of database trips.